Update a document in POST 'findOneAndUpdate' hook, but don't trigger middleware again
I am using a 'post' middleware hook in Mongoose to run some external promises and then possibly update the document with retrieved data values.
The issue is that updating the document triggers the 'post' middleware hook again.
Is there a property I can pass into the 'findOneAndUpdate' function to skip the middleware?
Here is some example code:
xxxSchema.post('findOneAndUpdate',async function (document) {
  try {
     if (true) {
        await this.model.findOneAndUpdate({_id}, {"$set" : { "a" : 1}})  // <-- pass a property into here to not trigger the pre/post middleware again
        console.log('done')
     }
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
  }
})


I fixed this by passing the following option into the post hook update - await this.model.findOneAndUpdate({_id}, dbUpdateObj, {includeResultMetadata: true}).  Then, in the pre-hook I used const options = this .getOptions();  if ("includeResultMetadata" in options) return next() and in the post hook I used if ("ok" in document) return; and this appears to work -- as long as I don't use that option anywhere else :)
